# Modelling of lenses with arbitrary concentric phase grating in Zemax

Tags: optics, lenses

I develop multifocal hybrid lenses that can be modelled as concentric phase gratings superpositioned onto a normal refractive lens body. These type of lenses are commonly used for multifocal intraocular lenses.

The diffractive grating are pure phase gratings, but of course with a pitch that varies with the radius. Their effect can be described fully with a phase retardation given as a direct function of the radius (it could be provided byfunction or by a lookup table with a horizontal resolution of 1µm is enough.).

Is there a known way to model this type of surface in Zemax? I could not find support for it among the standard surfaces.

Older versions of Zemax could not handle diffraction efficiency. Is there support for this in the newest OpticsStudio?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the Binary2 surface will do what you want. It will model a radially symmetric diffractive phase surface, on top of an arbitrary aspheric surface.  It uses equations to define the zones, not a table of zone locations. It still does not handle diffraction efficiency, you need to do that by using multiconfigurations.

If you meant to model several *different* regions of phase gratings (i.e. not just one phase grating over the whole surface), then as far as I know Zemax does not do that. You would have to write your own DLL to simulate it. This is made easier by the fact that if you look up User Defined Surface, you can find multiple examples of surfaces. You can then adapt parts of one or more of those for your new surface. At some point in your code, you would have to insert an if-then construct based on the distance of the ray from the optical axis to handle which zone the ray is in.

Comment: Thank you. I had also converged on Binary 2 as the best of the available surfaces. Regarding your question "If you meant to model several different regions of phase gratings (i.e. not just one phase grating over the whole surface)" I would say no, one grating is enough. But, the spacing between each phase peak has to to decrease with increasing radius, so that the grating period is fixed when plotted against the square of the radius. But this is how phase matched diffractive lenses always work, so I assume this is how the model work?

Comment: Yes, that is how phase matched diffractive lenses work, but that statement assumes that the only non-zero coefficient to the phase profile is the 2nd order coefficient. In general people will have a significant 2nd order coefficient, but other coefficients may also be non-zero (although usually smaller). The other coefficients basically add spherical aberration of different orders to the wavefront.